# Identifying a part from game console controller

Tags: identification

I need help identifying the following part. It came out of an old console game controller. It's labeled "SUP A9 103J". Googling it did not help. It's got ten pins and it was soldered into a space labeled "x9". I think it's some sort of crystal, but I'm not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is very likely a resistor network/array.
And is used where you have a lot of parallel signals you need pulled up or down or even individual resistors.

[image]

This picture is snipped from the Bournes catalogue.

and comes in many internal resistor styles

[image]

Comment: The "103J" is a dead giveaway. 10kohm, 5% tolerance.

Comment: Sure is, don't know the internal configuration though.  Multimeter anyone?

Comment: Looks like it's a 10k bussed resistor, just as you said. Pins 1-10 are all "ganged" together (I don't know the proper terminology).